# Hibernate org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: hibernate, orm, one-to-one

I am trying One-To-One unidirectional primary key xml mapping. when i try to save my Student object i get NonUniqueObjectException.

Student POJO

```
public class Student {

    private long studentId;
    private String name;
    private Locker locker;

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Locker getLocker() {
        return locker;
    }
    public void setLocker(Locker locker) {
        this.locker = locker;
    }
}
```

Student.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.avinash.dto.Student" table="STUDENT">
    <id name="studentId" type="long" column="STUDENT_ID">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">locker</param>

        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="NAME"></column>
    </property>

    <one-to-one name="locker" class="com.pramati.dto.Locker"  constrained="true">

    </one-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Locker POJO

```
public class Locker {

    private long lockerId;
    private String location;

    public long getLockerId() {
        return lockerId;
    }
    public void setLockerId(long lockerId) {
        this.lockerId = lockerId;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Locker.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.avinash.dto.Locker" table="LOCKER">
        <id name="lockerId" type="long" column="LOCKER_ID">
            <generator class="sequence"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="location" type="string">
            <column name="LOCATION"></column>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My java code is as follows

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionfactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Locker locker = new Locker();
    locker.setLocation("Hyderabad");

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("Avinash");
    student.setLocker(locker);

    Student student1 = new Student();
    student1.setName("Naresh");
    student1.setLocker(locker);

    session.save(student);
    session.save(student1);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    HibernateUtil.shutdown();
}
```

I am creating two different Student objects and assigning the same locker object to two Student objects in the same session. My doubt is

Since it is one to one relation my expectation is it should throw ConstraintViolationException, but why is it throwing NonUniqueObjectException. I have not overridden equals() and hashCode().

Comment: Could you post your entities here? you are trying to do is many-one(student-locker) entites, but why one-one? For every one student there is one locker, then use one-one

Comment: As suggested added my entities.since it is one to one relation one student can be assigned one locker. But here i am trying to assign the same locker to different students.When i run the above code it should throw constraint violation exception since i am assigning the same locker to the second student as well. But why do we get NonUniqueObjectException